# View question when answering

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, android-app

It is often critical to see the question when answering, particularly in math-related sites. Would it be possible to make the question itself visible in the Android App while answering a question?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this in the current app by hitting the <kbd><</kbd> button in the top left of the device. Your answer will be saved, you will go back to viewing the current questions and answers, and you'll get a big "Edit your answer draft" button on the bottom of the page to help send you back into resuming you answer.

This definitely needs to be more discoverable, I wouldn't want to hit that button either without knowing if it'll save everything I've written so far or not. Perhaps a "draft saved" notice at the top of the page would help, but let me know if the current functionality doesn't work as expected for you.