# Please make it possible to view the question when answering using the Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Often, I need to copy an identificator or variable name or another fragment from original question and paste to my answer. But if I push back button, I will have to write my answer anew. Thus, it may be useful to see an original question post when answer is being writing using Stack Exchange mobile application.

Comment: I don't use the Android app so I don't know but apparently [you already can](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229657/307988), is that not the case?

Comment: @Cai the proposed solution does not imply me. But you are right. The questions are the same. Do I have to delete my question or mark this as duplicated?

Answer (score -8):

[image]

Comment: My question relates to the Stack Exchange Android Application (see android-app tag).

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  - this isn't Alexander's answer

Comment: @RoryAlsop Oops, I've overseeing that subtle difference.